# Context State does not match Context Value using Typescript (with demo)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm using Typescript and React in this project. The TS type of the application state is a simple object with data, but the object I want pass to the Context.Provider value prop is a different shape; the state is stuffed into it's own prop, and a bunch of function handlers to update state are included.

Typescript is mad because I initialize a new Context with a values-only state, but the value I provide to the Contest.Provider includes functions and stashes the state behind it's own property.

**Typescript Types:**

```js
// Application State
// Data ONLY, no handlers. This can be serialized and saved between sessions if needed
export interface IAppContext {
  user: IUserData;
  sidemenu: {
    visible: boolean;
  }
}

// Context Provider Value
// State (from above) is in it's own property; also included are handlers for updating state
export interface IContextValue {
  globalState: IAppContext;
  updateUserData: (value: IUserData) => void;
  toggleSideMenu: () => void;
}
```

**React Global Context Component**

```
// default state values
export const defaultAppContext {
  user: {
    email: '', 
    id: ''
  },
  sidemenuIsVisible: false
}

// create context
export const AppContext = createContext(defaultAppContext);

// use in component
export const GlobalContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(appReducer, defaultAppContext);

  const contextValue: IContextValue = {
    globalState: state,
    updateUserData: (payload) => dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.UPDATE_USER, payload }),
    toggleSideMenu: () => dispatch({type: ACTIONS.TOGGLE_SIDEMENU,})
  };

  return <AppContext.Provider value={contextValue}>{children}</AppContext.Provider>;
};
```

**Errors**

```
Error: Type 'IContextValue' is missing the following properties from type 'IAppState': sidemenuIsVisible, user
Error: The expected type comes from property 'value' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ProviderProps<IAppState>'
```

The TS error is when I pass `contextValue` into the Provider value prop. When the context was initialized, it had a type of `IAppContext`, but the value I want to provide to any context consumers should include state AND handlers, so the value should be of type `IIContextValue`.

How can I initialize React Context with `IAppContext` consisting of only data, but then pass a value of type `IContextValue` to any consumers of the context?

**[CodeSandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-yonath-x5vf6?file=/src/context/index.tsx)**
Review the files in `/src/context`

**Possible workaround** - I do this to work around the issue, but I don't it's the best solution.

```
export const AppContext = createContext((defaultAppContext as unknown) as IContextValue);
```

Comment: Why not add default values for updateUserData and toggleSideMenu and pass in a full IContextValue to createContext?

Comment: idk... it's not how I want to do it. Unfortunately, that may be the scenario. It seems weird to mix the data store with methods used to update the store. I'd like to keep them separate if possible. I'll probably end up doing what you're suggesting.